# How to only allow one file to be dropped into listbox control c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing a windows form app that compares 2 pdf files in c#, to do this the user will drop the 2 files into 2 separate list boxes in my case one is "original" and one is "new", for validation purposes i was wondering if i would be able to limit the number of files being dropped to 1 per list box.

```
  public Compare()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AllowDrop = true;
            OriginalDrop_LstBox.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(OriginalDrop_LstBox_DragDrop);
            OriginalDrop_LstBox.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(OriginalDrop_LstBox_DragEnter);
            NewDrop_LstBox.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(NewDrop_LstBox_DragDrop);
            NewDrop_LstBox.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(NewDrop_LstBox_DragEnter);
        }



 private void OriginalDrop_LstBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

        private void OriginalDrop_LstBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                OriginalDrop_LstBox.Items.Add(s[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you drop a file and then it reads the lines and that's what goes in the list box? In that case, all you need to do is check if the list box is already populated and reject the change if it already has stuff in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the data and deny it when the count doesn't match what you expect:

```
private void OriginalDrop_LstBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
{
    var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    if (files.Length == 1 && OriginalDrop.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
```